# Phpstorm doesn't know how to run Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, phpstorm

I've tried all I could found here and googling. Include paths, external libraries, interpreter settings...

Whenever I try to run my theme's `index.php` file:

```
C:\XAMPP\php\php.exe "C:\path\to\project\wp-content\themes\MYTHEME\index.php"

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\path\to\project\wp-content\themes\MYTHEME\index.php on line 1

Process finished with exit code 255
```

So yes on line 1 I'm just calling my header.

Turns out it's trying to run `index.php` like a standalone file, **but ignoring the whole Wordpress instalation** (that I have included from different angles). Certainly it nows where `get_header()` is because I can control click it and it'll bring me to the file it's declared in, no problems.

It correctly detects XAMP's PHP interpreter too.

It also works well if I just visit the site typing my localhost URL in the browser. It just won't work through Phpstorm.

Comment: I found my answer. Anyways, typically it will run the file as if it is php. You would need to include the file with the function definition or some sort of wordpress config that includes the file. Functions defined in other files aren't automatically available. And I'm assuming you aren't including because it says the error is on line 1. If I am wrong, please correct. Either way though you should include some code so we don't have to just guess.

Comment: Somebody deleted my comment and I don't know why. Anyways, I was saying that index.php has only one line of code (also being the error in line 1, posting the rest of the code would be pointless), just the get_header(). This is a clean WP install, clean theme, all on XAMPP. How do I have to tell Phpstorm to run the other WP files? That's indeed what I'm asking here.

Comment: what version are you using?
phpstorm 8.0 have wordpress integration in the project setting that you need to enable first.

Comment: When I posted this I had 7.1.3. Now I have the 8th version and doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Why are you opening the theme and not the index `C:\XAMPP\php\php.exe "C:\path\to\project\index.php"` ?

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea What's the reason you try to run your theme? Theme is only view, you cannot run a part of application, you should rather login to wordpress dashboard, select your theme, and then run wordpress and not your theme

Comment: For some reason when I run the WP index it doesn't load the contents (stored in the DB I guess) so besides header and footer, nothing else is loaded. I'm used to developing usable homemade php projects and not this WP thing. I'm really puzzled that I haven't been able to find a good tutorial on WP theme development workflow. Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are directly calling theme's index file which is not correct way, as your theme must be using some default functions of WordPress, like `get_header()` in this case.

So you need to make sure `wp-load.php` is loaded to make all WP functions available to use. You have two way for that:

1) Call root `index.php` so everything will be loaded by default.

2) Call theme's `index.php` but add Below code in that:

```
if(!function_exists('get_header')) {
    require_once( '/wp-load.php' );
}
```

However this is not good way :)

Comment: Ok but what's the phpstorm WP plugin useful for then? It should load whatever it is needed beforehand, all WP files are just there for phpstorm to load them, and yet I have to run manually what I don't want to run in order to then navigate somehow to my particular php file and then start to work? And do that in every run? I'd like to read or view how a phpstorm WP them dev workflow is supposed to be.

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea WP is never developed in such a way that you can run your theme files directly. It is expected that you run your `index.php` from root and it will take it further.

Comment: Okey, again, is there any phpstorm+wordpress decent documentation I can read?

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea you can try below links:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCNy74qzekg

Comment: Yes, I've seen that video in the past, and it talks about eeeverything EXCEPT what I'm trying to figure out: running/debugging WP in Phpstorm. I don't understand how the most IDE used in the world and the blog/CMS most used in the world, have so little documentation. I'm left with poking around, figuring out stuff wasting plenty of time. Haven't been able to find any article about this, blog post, manual... I'm open to anything.