# Wordpress site redirect error while move from one server to another

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I got an error after move wordpress site from one server to another. Here is the browser output error. Any help please? The site have multisite facility in wordpress.

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: On which server you transfer your website linux/windows or other?

Comment: Is it the same domain, or domain name is changed also? Try to check .htaccess, is it works or not.

Comment: both are different domain

Comment: i try to remove .htaccess and place default .htaccess too but not working

Comment: @Technogupshup,I have posted answer of your question,Please check it & let me know !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Technogupshup,Please try to reset you permalink structure and then set your custom permalinks again ( via wp-admin ).

**OR**

You can use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-fix-disable-canonical-redirects-pack/) plugin that makes WordPress' default permalinks behavior work on the Concentric/XO Communications shared hosting platform too.

Comment: But i am not able to access admin section due to this error.

Comment: Can you please check define( 'WP_SITEURL') in wp-config file ? Is it proper ? Also check all other constants of the wp-confing file.

Comment: I solved that issue but getting a new one error "Error establishing a database connection". I have multisite in wordpress.Siteurl,Homeurl in database is ok. And also wp-config is configure correct.

Comment: @Technogupshup,Good.If my answer helps to you can you please accept my answer ? Also for multi site connection issue,you can visit forum [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/installing-multisite-yields-error-establishing-database-connection-error)

Comment: Warning: require(/public_html/wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/index.php on line 17

Comment: Check my answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289283/phpstorm-doesnt-know-how-to-run-wordpress/26381144#26381144) link in stackoverflow to get it resolve this issue.