# Wordpress warning while migrate from one server to another

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I got warning after move from one server to another. I already updated my site and home url in database. The warning is describe below.

> Warning: require(/public_html/wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/public_html/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php52/lib/php') in //public_html/index.php on line 17

wp-blog-header.php file is correct. Placed on root.

Here is the code of index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Comment: try to update once you permalink from admin panel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress site redirect error while move from one server to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712334/wordpress-site-redirect-error-while-move-from-one-server-to-another)

Comment: @BhumiShah Thanks for such a helpful information. Unfortunately i forgot to change permalink after migrate from one server to another. Now my site is up and running well

Comment: Any help for multisite? Because when i true multisite option my site go down. If do flase multisite then site working fine. I really need multisite in my website.